# Python Twisted: Create SSLv2 context

Tags: python, ssl, twisted, pyopenssl

I'm making an game server emulator, the game is pretty old and uses insecure SSLv2 protocol for communicating, i can decrypt packet trough this:

`ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, keyfile="Certificates/bfbc2.key", certfile="Certificates/bfbc2.crt", ssl_version=SSL.SSLv2_METHOD, do_handshake_on_connect=True, ciphers="DEFAULT")`

As you can see i used two ssl modules (`ssl`, and `OpenSSL`).
I realized that making that huge project from basically 'zero' is too much work, and its inpossible in some way.

`Twisted`can do things better than `socket` module, so i decided to switch it.

And here is problem, i don't know how to create SSLv2 context.
I tryed this:

`SSLContext = ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory('Certificates/bfbc2.key', 'Certificates/bfbc2.crt', sslmethod=ssl.SSL.SSLv2_METHOD)`

But it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: No such protocol
```

How to get SSLv2 working in Twisted?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the traceback:

`File "python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/ssl.py", line 113, in cacheContext
    ctx = self._contextFactory(self.sslmethod)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 600, in __init__
    raise ValueError("No such protocol")
ValueError: No such protocol`

The exception comes from the OpenSSL package, part of pyOpenSSL.  pyOpenSSL has dropped support for SSLv2.  You may be able to find an older version of pyOpenSSL which still supports SSLv2 (you may also have to find an older version of Twisted with which the older pyOpenSSL is compatible).

Another option would be to terminate SSLv2 with a separate tool such as `stunnel`.

Similarly, you may need to make sure your build of the native OpenSSL library actually still supports SSLv2.  Recent versions are likely to have been compiled without this feature (for the obvious reasons).

Comment: So why i can create SSLv2 socket using ssl, OpenSSL, and socket modules?

Comment: The traceback clearly says you can't with `OpenSSL`.  `ssl` and `socket` module are actually only one thing and they're separate from the `OpenSSL` package.  What you can do with them and what you can do with `OpenSSL` will necessarily differ based on their implementations and interface guarantees.

Comment: Your pyOpenSSL installation may be using a newer version of OpenSSL than `socket` / `ssl` are using.  It's pretty hard to say from here, though (ie, there is not enough information in your question to make any definitive statement about why the behaviors differ).

Answer (score 0):

SSLv2 (and often even SSLv3) is usually unsupported today by OpenSSL (i.e. not compiled in) because it is insecure. Since Twisted ultimately uses OpenSSL you get `No such protocol` when trying to use SSLv2.